# Feeding data from web socket through observable in service classes to component

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

I have an application which connects to a web socket to receive data. The data feed  is one way only, so the client will not be pushing data to the server

I have created a WebSocketService which subscribes to the web socket (using stomp) and then pushes the data to the observable when a message comes in

```
private createSocketObservable<T>(topic: string) {
    return Observable.create((obs: Observer<T>) => {
        // Subscribe to the topic, and on each message the observer pushes the parsed data
        const subscription = this.stompClient.subscribe(topic, (message: Message) => {
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(message.body);
            obs.next(jsonData);
        });
        this.subscriptions.push(subscription);

    });
}
```

I then want to have different service classes that subscribe to different topics on the web socket and pass the data that is coming from the above observable to a component, possibly modifying or filtering that data on the way (for example using map).

I have created an abstract WebSocketSubscription class which these services can extend which contains the observable that is returned from the WebSocketService

```
export abstract class WebSocketSubscriber<T> {
    abstract topic: string;

    webSocketFeed: Observable<T>;

    constructor(private webSocketService: WebSocketService) {
        this.webSocketService.connect().then(() => {
        this.webSocketFeed = this.webSocketService.getObservable(this.topic);
    });
}
```

How can I now set it up so that any service class that extends WebSocketSubscriber can call functions such as map, distinct, filter etc. and that a component can subscribe to the result of that feed?

Also the subscription on the component will probably occur before the web-socket is connected, my initial thoughts were to use a promise to wait until the connect was made, but I would be interested to hear if there is an RxJs way to handle this too

Comment: You need to use subjects

Comment: @Fartab can you elaborate?

Comment: I will write an example in the next answer

Comment: which library you use for stomp in angular?

Comment: right now I am just importing the webstomp-client, the backend is using SockJS so I need to call stomp.over(SockJS) to create the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ReplaySubject` you can remember previous topic messages for the services which subscribe later:

```
@Injectable()
export class WebSocketServiceService {

  private socketSubjects: { [key: string]: ReplaySubject<any> } = {}

  private createSocketObservable<T>(topic: string) {
    if(this.socketSubjects[topic]){
      return this.socketSubjects[topic].asObservable();
    }
    else{
      this.socketSubjects[topic] = new ReplaySubject();
      const subscription = this.stompClient.subscribe(topic, (message: Message) => {
      const jsonData = JSON.parse(message.body);
      this.socketSubjects[topic].next(jsonData);
    });
    this.subscriptions.push(subscription);
    }
  }
}
```

When creating ReplaySubject you can set the memory limit:

`new ReplaySubject(5) // remember last 5 items`

Comment: if you have any question, ask to describe more

Comment: So you're suggesting that each component that is related to a topic gets it from this class? Or a service gets it from this class? My thoughts were that this would feed another service, which could then modify the data before passing it on to a component, getting that working is the bit that confuses me

Comment: use this service directly in your components and apply filter, map,.. on retrieved observable